# Where's the line between health and human physiology?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are several questions on Health.SE that I would consider as being off-topic, as they are not about health, but about general human physiology/biology. Examples are

[Is "big boned" real or not?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/4217/is-big-boned-real-or-not)

[Is there an evolutionary reason why so many white matter tracts decussate in the brainstem and spinal chord?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/3847/is-there-an-evolutionary-reason-why-so-many-white-matter-tracts-decussate-in-the)

[What is the name of the sense that keeps track of where your body parts are?](https://health.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/what-is-the-name-of-the-sense-that-keeps-track-of-where-your-body-parts-are)

They aren't many, but I was wondering whether questions like that should be closed as off-topic (and, if they are on-topic there, maybe migrated to Biology).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. If you come across these, you can flag them for moderator attention rather than making meta posts as well.

For the big boned, I migrated it to biology. For the sense question, since it has a correct answer and is somewhat older, I elected to leave it on the site, since I don't think a better answer would be gotten on a different site. I am inquiring about the third.

If there is any question that you feel needs moderator intervention such as should be on another site, you can use the flag link under the question, select "In need of moderator intervention", and explain your reasoning. That's part of what the site needs, is strong users supplementing the efforts of the moderators. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, that helps :-) And I think it's good to leave the older questions, they are just examples here. Generally, it would also be okay to vote to close with a reason indicating that it's off-topic, right? I don't want to overuse the moderator flags :-)

Comment: @YviDe - My rule of thumb on other sites is if I think a post is off topic, I VTC as such. If I feel like it could fit on another site, I then also flag for mod attention. That's how the system is designed, users supporting the moderators. It's easier reviewing 7 flags, than going through every new question every day.

Comment: why shouldn't we allow question about human physiology?

Comment: @Ooker - If it is pertinent to a health question, absolutely. If it doesn't have health implications (such as how does succinyl-coa fit in the Krebs cycle) then it's a better fit on other sites (In the example case, biology).